# facebook register/login

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to implement facebook connect to my website, and i have couple questions.

1: Is it possible to register user in my website using his current facebook email/password.

Let's say user clicks on link `Register via facebook` and then he have to give me permisions to access his password, email, etc... and after that is done i put that info in my own database and he will be able to login with that account any time he wants without needing to give me permisions any time in the future.

2: If that kind of registration is not possible, what's other solution would be the best for me? Because i need to somehow keep track of that user who logged in with facebook, because he can upload photos, send messages etc.

Anyways, i'm quite new with facebook and similar things, so i'm really lost here, hope some one can help me :)

**EDIT** Thank you all for wonderful answers it helped me a lot, now all that's left is to read documentation :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is, it is possible to get the information of the user. But it is rather complicated, when you have never dealt with it.

First you need to send the user to the following link:

```
https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=your-client-id&redirect_uri=xxx&scope=listof-information-you-want
```

Facebook will then return your client to the uri specified, if the user rejected it will give a reason. If it is not you will get an code in urlencoded format.

This code is needed for the following step, the request of the access token:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?redirect_uri=xxx&client_id=xxx&client_secret=xxx&code=xxxx
```

This will give back an access token, if the authorization didn't fail.

After that you can ask for the information you want:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?method=GET&metadata=true&format=json&access_token=access_token
```

This will include a facebook uid, which is unique for all users. Store it and you can discern between a register and login.

This is roughly the process for any oauth2 application.

Facebook will not ask repeatedly for permissions after the user granted them to you. So you can store the access token and reuse it for backend stuff and also use the same procedure you use for register for login.

Answer (score 3):

- You can never access the user's password from Facebook even with his/her permission, so the user will always have to *authenticate via Facebook* and have Facebook pass you the user id of the logged in user once authentication succeeds. You can store all kinds of other data locally, but not enough to authenticate the user yourself.
- Once the user is authenticated, you'll have access to the user's Facebook user id via the API, which should be enough to connect all kinds of information to that specific user.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook does not provide access to accounts when passwords are taken from your controls. It provides it own canvas for login information. Therefore you cannot use your first approach to store passwords in your databases. [Check this out](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/).

You can however store email addresses once user logins into his account using the facebook sdks. Check this out [link](http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Writing-your-First-Facebook-Application-v6.aspx)  for the example of C# SDK sample code.
You can use the Facebook APIs to fetch user email-id, photos, friendslist and other information and then play around accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't get access to the users password - only email if you ask for it.
2. Best way would be to have a table of users and their Facebook account id's.

If you want to allow users to sign up without Facebook then have a nullable field for their password and facebook id, and also have a field for username - which you could populate from Facebook if they register via that route.